# Hibernate default naming @Column with postgres

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I am implementing an application in spring-boot with the database Postgres, I want customized column name i.e in camelcase

```
@Column(name = "customerId")
private Integer customerId;

@Column(name = "accountNumber")
private Integer accountNumber;
```

for that, I have added all properties

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming_strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl`
```

which I got from spring docs and StackOverflow but none of is working in my case, every time column names created with these names: `accountnumber` `customerid`

I am trying to override with these codes:

```
public class RealNamingStrategyImpl extends SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy
    implements Serializable {

public static final PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl INSTANCE = new PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl();

@Override
public Identifier toPhysicalTableName(Identifier name, JdbcEnvironment context) {
    return new Identifier(name.getText(), name.isQuoted());
}

@Override
public Identifier toPhysicalColumnName(Identifier name, JdbcEnvironment context) {
    return new Identifier(name.getText(), name.isQuoted());
}
```

}

But didn't get the expected result.
can anyone help me with that?
Thank you!

Comment: Please share your properties file.

Comment: Does postgresql even support uppercase column names? If I understand this correctly - they are converted to lower case per default, if you don't quote them. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive

Comment: I have shared my properties above as well:

Comment: @TomStroemer but I need my column names the way I have specified, and yes by manually getting into DB and using Alter I am able to do but I want JPA should auto-create the way I defined.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58849104/7598851) answer provides information on how to customize column names.

Comment: Thank you for responding, I got my answer, as I have mentioned that I was using Postgres using spring boot and there are some special rules to put a capital in a table or in column names: we need to use quotation.
example :@Column(name = "\"customerId\"")